# Definition of factorial function for sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recursion

Why is the factorial function expressed in terms of $(n+1)$ for sets?

$0! = 1$
$(n+1)! = (n+1) \times n! $ for all $n$ $\in\mathbb{N}$

Instead of the more "common"

$0! = 1$
$n! = n \times (n-1)!$

Comment: Set $m=n+1$ - why do you think there is an issue here?

Comment: And.. where are the 'sets' here?

Comment: @MarkBennet I do not think there is an issue. I have only ever seen it defined in therms of n-1... So seeing it as (n+1) ... just seemed counter intuitive. Adriano's answer makes it perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either definition is acceptable. The only difference here is that the first definition assumes that:
$$
n \in \mathbb N = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}
$$
while the second definition assumes that:
$$
n \in \mathbb Z^+ = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}
$$